# getting wrong distance for GPS coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, cllocationdistance, cllocationcoordinate2d

```
double lat1 = coordinate1.latitude * M_1_PI/180;
double lat2 = coordinate2.latitude * M_1_PI/180;
double lon1 = coordinate1.longitude * M_1_PI/180;
double lon2 = coordinate2.longitude * M_1_PI/180;
double r = 6371;
double dlat = lat2 - lat1;
double dlon = lon2 - lon1;
double a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2);
double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
distance = distance + (r * c * 1000);
```

here it is the code i'm using and it will add the distance continously for the new location of user from his first location. pls tell me i'm doing anything wrong and i'm getting the `distance` in meters. the result is always coming like this.

if original distance is between the coordinates is 10.97 meters, for me it was only 1.097 meters
Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CoreLocation methods.
For example this method will find the shortest distance between array of locations and single location:

```
 + (NSInteger)distanceFrom:(NSArray*)locations toLocation:(CLLocation*)myLocation
{
    if(!locations || !locations.count) return -1;
    NSMutableArray *distance = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (CLLocation *loc in locations)
    {

        float latitudeB = loc.coordinate.latitude;
        float longitudeB = loc.coordinate.longitude;
        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeB  longitude:longitudeB];
        CLLocationDistance distanceBetweenAB = [myLocation distanceFromLocation:locB];
        [distance addObject:@(distanceBetweenAB)];

    }
    int distInt = [[distance valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] intValue];;
    return distInt;
}
```

Comment: what is that `APRGPSLocation`?

Comment: Sorry, it's my own class. You can us CLLocation class instead. I'll edit the answer

Comment: i've tried the above method, but i'm not getting atleast approx value. thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make semse m_1_pi = 1/pi,

you are dividing longitude in  degrees / (180 *pi)

it should be degrees *pi / 180  or degrees *M_PI / 180.0 will give you radians